# SSRS Published report from MySQL DB shows blank/empty rows

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, blank-line

I have created a very simple report in Visual Studio (also tried it in Report Builder) that just returns 10 rows from a table in a **MySQL** (Not MSSQL) database. I changed the background and foreground color to make sure I could clearly see the rows in the report.

There are no parameters and it does not use a stored procedure. It's a straightforward SQL query:

```
select TASK_INSTANCE_ID, TASK_NAME, ASSIGNED_NAME, CREATED_DTTM
from task_instance where created_dttm > date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)
limit 10
```

Here's the result when previewing the report in Visual Studio. You can see that it is showing 10 rows of data.
[image: Preview showing 10 rows of data]

I then publish that report to our SSRS server:
[image: Output of publishing the report]

And when I view that report on the SSRS server I get 10 blank rows.
[image: Blank rows when viewing report in SSRS server]

To confirm that I was actually seeing the rows and they were just blank, I changed the query to return just 5 rows. This shows that there are now only 5 blank rows, but with the defined background color.
[image]

For reference, I also created a simple report from an Oracle DB and published it to the same folder on the same SSRS server. This report works just fine.

[image: Oracle report that works just fine]

So it appears to be something related to using a **MySQL** DB, but I have not been able to find anything that explains what I'm doing wrong. Any pointers/help will be greatly appreciated.

I then tried to add a couple new columns to the SQL query.

1. I used the ROW_NUMBER function to get the rownum of each returned row
2. I added a dummy column with a constant value for each row

Works fine in the Query Designer:
[image: Query Designer]

Works fine in the Preview:
[image: Preview]

Shows the new columns when published to SSRS, but still shows blank cells for the other columns:
[image: Published report]

Comment: Did you check your data source? Usually when a Previewed report has different data than a deployed report, it's due to having a data source that points to a different environment (i.e. Report checked in TEST server from SSRS but deployed to report server with PROD server connection).

Comment: cloud or on premise? What version of MySQL you’re using?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes I have checked the data source and have tried using different data sources for different dev vs test vs prod databases. Same result for all. And I would expect the same result since it's simple query that pulls 5 rows from a table that has 100s of thousands of rows in every database.

Comment: Both SSRS and MySql are on premise.MySQL 8+

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is/was the same as mine then I think you will find that if you export your report to excel from the report-portal that all of the data that you expect to see is in fact present.

After some digging into the report properties and trying page width settings etc. I found that I had different values for the `CanGrow` property of the cells in the row and once I set them all to be the same -- `True` in my case -- then the report rendered as expected.

I am thinking that the reason that Excel showed the data is because it effectively ignores the CanGrow setting so having a mixture of them didn't matter.

I hope that this helps -- you or others who encounter it later -- as it was a really bizarre thing to encounter...